# Is there a way to add an https-rss feed to Outlook 2013 (Windows)?

Tags: https, outlook, rss

I'm having trouble adding an **https**-rss-feed to Outlook **2013** on Windows.
When I add a http-rss-feed, there's no problem, I can add any http-rss-feeds.

***I have to add that this is my pc at work, so I can't install any other software. Add-ins for Outlook are possible though. Also a portable version of an app is possible too.***

Only when I add an **https**-rss-feed, it doesn't show up with the rss-feeds, and I get no error message.

I've looked on the internet, and the problem should not occur with Outlook **2016**.

Is there an addon I can use or a script to get this to work?

It's my office-computer, so I'm not able to upgrade to Outlook **2016** myself.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate a live Twitter feed in a Webkit supported email like IOS. When it comes to non-webkit emails, I suggest you consider a dynamic image to present the RSS feed or Twitter feed.

> We created a simple web page of just the Twitter feed using the same HTML and CSS from the email. We simply took a screenshot of the feed at the same dimensions of 600×902 through the command line utility wkhtmltoimage and dynamically updated that same image every 10 seconds.

- https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-code-a-live-dynamic-twitter-feed-in-html-email

I hope that helps.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm on Windows (Office/Outlook 2013) and can't install any other email program because it's my pc at work, the only option is use a portable version of a program or use outlook addins. We are also behind a proxy-server, so fetching twitter or something isn't possible. Sorry that I didn't include it in my original question. I'll edit it.